# Main function in C programming

Tags: c, microprocessors

I am facing a problem when debugging a microprocessor. It resets from time to time and I found there is an initialization call at the beginning of the main() function, which could be the reason to trigger the resetting.

There is a while loop after the initialization, which is supposed to run all the time, however, if an error detected a few times, it will abort this while loop and go to the end of the main function.

I would like to know what happen to the microprocessor when the program goes to the end of main function. What factors can trigger it to restart from the beginning of the main function? I know re-powering the chip could trigger the program to run from the beginning, but I don't see the processor actually restarted, because the voltage is stable at 3.3V during resetting.

Any advices could be helpful.

Comment: Please post your code and tell us the model of your used µC.

Comment: It depends on the specific compiler and standard library (if any) that you are using.

Comment: The behavior of `main` in embedded systems depends on the implementation. Rebooting the device is a perfectly sane implementation, but so is shutting down. In general, you can't expect `return 0` in `main` to return to the OS.

Comment: There are several ways for a reset to happen which are documented in the specs of the specific microcontroller. Certainly you will find there what happens when it reaches the end of main (FIY the `main` isn't the beginning, `_start` is)

Comment: Have established for sure that the code reaches the end of the `main` function or is that an assumption? A micro can reset for any number of reasons.

Comment: Do you mean, a "microcontroller?"  It is running on top for an OS?  You really need to provide more detail

Comment: Is there a fault handler you can put a breakpoint in, to determine the reset reason?  Or, can you print the contents of the fault handler or reset reason on startup?

Comment: Thanks for all the advices. I am not the developer of this firmware and I cannot contact that developer any more. And I cannot use a debug mode to put a breakpoint or so. I only have parts of source code here. The processor is "i.MX6ULL: i.MX 6ULL Single-Core Processor with Arm® Cortex®-A7 Core"

Comment: 3.3 volts is not enough for some micros. You might like to assure yourself you aren't getting an external reset too.

Comment: I believe it is the software side issue. I saw the error descripted in the while loop happens and then the board was initialized. So I know when the error happens and it could be not corrected after a while, it will go out of the while loop and to the end of the Main function. I would like to know what would happen in the software side after it run to the end of the main function.

Comment: As already said, there is no single general behavior. If you don't have the source code, your only bet is the machine code. It is possible, even though laborious, to analyze what will happen. Common alternatives are: reboot or a tight endless loop doing nothing. -- Please note, that you can debug binary code without source. You will be on assembly level, though.